# How to decide in which language to write an algorithm that iterates through large amounts of data?

Tags: algorithms

I am attempting to implement an algorithm that takes in a massive array of data, and iterates through each element in this array. For each element, it will either create an new array and put the element inside it or insert it in some existing array based on qualities of the element.

How to decide which language is the best for implementing this algorithm that will iterate through an extremely large array of data?

My initial guess would be a high level language such as Java or Python but I am interested if there are advantages to using other languages to implement this algorithm.

Comment: *Any* language can be made to do what you are asking.  The 'what language should I learn' is indeed off topic as described in the [help/on-topic] and further elaborated in [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/40980) on our meta site.

Comment: Find out which languages will process extremely large arrays of data, and then pick one you like.

Comment: what language you should use next is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/40980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't get hung up on this. It is paralysis by analysis. What if I told you Haskell was the best language? Would that help you? What if you don't know Haskell?

That is why this is subjective and off-topic, but it is still an issue that beginners struggle with ("Which language is better...")

The best language for you, right now, is the language you are most comfortable with, assuming it is compatible with the problem environment. Worrying about language before you start implies you are worried about performance, but since you've written nothing to measure, yet, you don't have a performance problem, so this is a form of premature optimization. Don't optimize prematurely.

However, in interest of pragmatism, I cannot honestly think of a top-20 language that is *not* a good language for what you describe. That is, until you observe a performance problem. And any language has the potential to exhibit a performance problem.